# Gridview Hyperlinkfield using DataNavigateUrlFormatString with Ampersand

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

So I have gridview pulling fields from a table and my hyperlinkfield is used to go to a specific page for that row to get more detailed data. Everything seems to work great except when the field used in the hyperlinkfield has an ampersand. I assume it is reading the ampersand as something else and so it doesn't bring up the proper info because the ampersand is in the name in the database.

Hyperlinkfieldcode:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" Text="{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="item.aspx?name={0}" DataTextField="Name" />
```

Example:

A clicking on the name "test item" would take you to mysite.com/item.aspx?name=test%20item and this works.

However, clicking on "test & test item" it takes you to mysite.com/item.aspx?name=test%20item%20&%20item which does not work. It just pulls up a page with blank info.

What can I do to fix this?

**Update:**

I converted the hyperlinkfield to a hyperlink inside a template field, but the url is now coming out weird.the url now comes out like mysite.com/item.aspx?name=System.Int32%5b%5d

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' DataNavigateUrlFields="Name" NavigateUrl='<%# "name.aspx?name=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode({0}.ToString())%>'  DataTextField="Name" />
                          </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer was incomplete (due to not being able to see the entire code). This answer will contain the missing elements.

The main object is to [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) the data field **Name**, so that it can be used as (part of) a url link .

**1** - First we must ensure that the field "`Name`",  is listed as `DataKeyNames` for the `GridView` as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Name"  ...
```

**2** - Secondly (if using a  `navigateURL`) create a TemplateField i.e. (`asp:TemplateField` ) and use `Eval()` method to access the DataField in conjunction with `UrlEncode()` .

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="NameLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "name.aspx?name=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString())%>'  ></asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Option 2** Alternatively you can use a HyperLinkField and DataNavigateURL but you should still designate `Name` as a `DataKeyNames` .

Hope this works with no problems. Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Happy coding and Cheers,

Comment: This is pretty much what I was doing, but I guess mine had some slight difference because using your exact code works. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Stoked its all working for you know. I think there is good info here for others as well. Thanks for accepting my answer. This process taught me how to better answer questions.

Comment: I agree completely! I really appreciate your help!